# What is $E \left[\lvert Y-y\rvert\right]$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

This is a part of a larger problem I want to solve. The larger problem is to show that :

$$\frac{d}{dy}E \left[\lvert Y-y\rvert\right]=P\left[ Y\le y \right]-P \left[Y \ge y \right]$$

(I want to try to solve this myself so I am only looking for a small hints/ideas but I just wanted to include it for context)

To start with, I want to somehow find an alternative expression of this:

$$E \left[\lvert Y-y\rvert\right]$$

---

**What I have tried so far:**

I know that $E[g(X)]=\int_{-\infty}^\infty g(x) f_X(x)dx$, where $f_X(x)$ is the probability density function (PDF) of $X$. I also know that $E[aX+b]=aE[X]+b$. If it were just $E[Y-y]$ I could write:

$$E[Y-y]=E[Y]-y$$

and if it were just $E[\lvert Y\rvert]$ I could write:

$$E[\lvert Y\rvert]=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \lvert y\rvert f_Y(y)dy$$

I am just not sure how to apply these together. Any ideas/hints?

Comment: Is $Y$ a continuous random variable?

Comment: You are on the right track -- note that $g(Y) = |Y - y|$ is still a function of $Y$. Now be careful, you don't want to use $y$ for your variable of integration.

Comment: @MeesdeVries I am kind of confused now. Is $y$ just a constant here? Otherwise wouldn't $Y-y$ be zero for every $y$? For example if the random variable $Y$ takes the value $y$ then $(Y=y)-y=0$ right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

Use the layer cake representation: if $X$ is a nonnegative random variable, then
$$
E[X]=\int_0^\infty P(X>x)\,dx.
$$
You can apply this directly to $X=|Y-y|$, or you can write $|Y-y|$ as a difference of two nonnegative random variables, $|Y-y|=(Y-y)^+-(Y-y)^-$.

Comment: Can I just assume that $X$ is a non-negative random variable?

Comment: @Nullspace $|Y - y|$ is obviously nonnegative. Mike is stating to set $X = |Y - y|$ in the formula above.

Comment: @Mike Earnest Thanks that helps. I think splitting this into two integrals will also lead me straight to the statement I want to show.

Comment: @Mike Earnest Just a follow up question that I also asked in the commtents. I "little y" $y$ a constant? If not,  wouldn't I just be subtracting $(Y=y)-y=0$ all the time?

Comment: @Nullspace I think you are forgetting the superscript $+$ and $-$. Recall that $X^+$ is defined to be the random variable equal to $X$ when $x\ge 0$, and $0$ when $X<0$. This means $X=X^+-X^-$ (and we apply this when $X=Y-y$).