# Show that $\frac{d}{dy}E [\lvert Y-y \rvert]=P(Y \le y)-P(Y \ge y)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

**This is a follow up question to this question:** [What is $E[\lvert Y-y\rvert]?$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4143221/what-is-e-left-lvert-y-y-rvert-right)

In the end I want to show that: $$\frac{d}{dy}E[\lvert Y-y\rvert]=P(X \le x)-P(X \ge x)$$

In the linked question I was given two hints:

1. For any non-negative random variable $X$ we can write: $$E[X]=\int_0^{\infty}P(X > x)dx$$
2. Write $\lvert Y-y\rvert$ as a sum of two non-negative random variables: $$\lvert Y-y\rvert=(Y-y)^+ -(Y-y)^-$$

---

**Here is what I have done so far:**

$$\begin{aligned} \frac{d}{dy}E[\lvert Y-y\rvert] &= \frac{d}{dy}E[(Y-y)^+-(Y-y)^-] \\ &= \frac{d}{dy} \left( E[(Y-y)^+]-E[(Y-y)^-]\right) \\ &= \frac{d}{dy}\left( \int_0^\infty P(Y-y \ge0)dy-\int_0^\infty P(Y-y < 0)dy \right)\\ & =\frac{d}{dy} \left( \int_0^{\infty}P(Y \ge y)dy-\int_0^\infty P(Y<y)dy \right) \\ &=P(Y\ge y)-P(Y <y) \not=P(Y\le y)-P(Y \ge y) \end{aligned}$$

---

**My questions:**

1. Obviously I am doing something wrong but I can't figure out where exactly. Line 3 feels kind of wrong to me but I am not sure what else to do. Any ideas?
2. This is a more conceptual question about the "meaning" of $\lvert  Y-y \rvert$ and $E[\lvert Y-y \rvert] $. Is $y$ just some fixed value here? As far as I understand the random variable $Y$ can take a range of values. So for example when my random variable takes the value $Y=y$, wouldn't $Y-y=0$ for all $y$?

Comment: If $Y=0$ then $E|Y-y|$ is not a differentiable function of $y$.

Comment: What is $t$ in  $\frac d{dt}$?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Ah sorry thats a typo. Should be $\frac{d}{dy}$. I don't quite understand what you mean by your first comment.

Comment: The statement is false since the derivative does not always exist.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy So you are saying the statement I am trying to show is false? This is the way it is stated on my problem set. The only additional information I am given is that $E[Y^2]< \infty$, $Y$ has some associated probability density and that ultimately I need to show that $$E[\lvert Y-m \rvert] \le E[\lvert Y-y\rvert]$$ where $m$ is the median. I am supposed to show the statement in my question first, then go on to show the statment in this comment.

Comment: The fact that $Y$ has a probability density is of significant importance here, since it excludes the case @KaviRamaMurthy talks about. The function $y\mapsto |y|$ is not differentiable in $y=0$, so your RV $Y$ has to bring something to the table which renders $E|Y-y|$ differentiable in $0$ (e.g. a probability density function).

Comment: @Jfischer Sorry I wasn't aware of that. I basically started this topic a couple of weeks ago so I am still struggling with the basics. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it goes like this:
$$\frac{d}{dy}E[|Y-y|]=\frac{d}{dy}\int_{\mathbb{R}}|z-y|p_Y(z)dz= \\
=\frac{d}{dy}\bigg(\int_y^\infty(z-y)p_Y(z)dz+\int_{-\infty}^y(y-z)p_Y(z)dz\bigg)= \\
\underbrace{=}_{\textrm{Leibniz}}-\int_y^\infty p_Y(z)dz+\int_{-\infty}^yp_Y(z)dz=\\
=-P(Y\geq y)+P(Y\leq y)$$

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Could you maybe explain why you chose the boundries of integration this way. Specifically, why did you chose to integrate from $y$ to $\infty$ and not $0$ to $\infty$ for example?

Comment: To seperate the $|z-y|$ into $-(z-y)$ and $z-y$. The change of the sign happens exactly at $z=y$.

Comment: @Jfischer Ah of course! I missed that we are integrating w.r.t $z$ and not $y$. Thanks!

Comment: @Nullspace yes I had to choose another integration variable